# How does one create a looping animation on the Z axis in Blender 2.8?

Tags: animation, loop

I've read a dozen posts on loop animation, but nothing seems to work in version 2.8 of Blender. I have a simple need to rotate a UFO 360 continuously during an animation with other things going on.

My goal is to setup a 360 loop while moving it through space and perhaps other Y and X rotations. I've been trying to use the F-Curve Generator, but it instantly changed the Y and X rotations even though I've clicked the LOCKED button those axis.

What is a viable way of doing this in Blender 2.8?

Comment: because I guess the local Z axis of your object must be a little bit tilted compared to the Z global axis, so you should make sure your object is aligned on the Z global axis, make it rotate, then parent it to an empty, and tilt and move the empty

Comment: see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Both of your suggestions did the trick! Ty for the thread link!