# Rotating a fan rotor on a tilt

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a model of fan rotor that goes on a tilted wing of a drone.  I want it to rotate on its center but it needs to be at an angle to fit the wing.  I can get it to rotate on the Y axis and set keyframes for it but when I tilt it to place it in the wing it jumps back to level when I start the animation??  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "it jumps back to level when I start the animation" -> what do you mean? Maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: Thank you.  I think that reference may be exactly what I was searching for. As for what I meant, the rotor is level when I set the pivot keyframes then I rotate it at angle and hit play and it goes back to level and the original location which I know is where the keyframe was set, but this article adds an empty which I never thought about doing.  Thanks again for the reply.