# Struggling to rotate in the correct axis It seems simple but gets strange when I keyframe

Tags: 3d-cursor

[image: If I set to median point it rotates from here but 3d cursor seems to rotate from the same point]I bought a model and I have separated the blade and now I wish to animate it! Problem is when I set it to median point it's sky high. I played around with a few different settings and eventually settled on using the 3D cursor as the point of rotation. When I grab the Gizmo on the Y and rotate it it looks like it's doing exactly what I ned to do however when I Add key frames to this rotation the whole set of blades rotates up into the sky.

Very new to blender so go easy on me if it's obvious!
Appreciate any help!

Thank you
[image: how it rotates after key framing]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: Using an empty solved it thank you so much!