# How can I create a proper rotation for the dial

Tags: modeling, animation, transform-orientation

I have those dials that I made, and they are slightly tilted, so they are not perfectly aligned to the axis. When I try to rotate the dial, it doesn't work as I want it to. I try changed the "transform orientations" but that didn't make any difference.  What else can I try in order to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: You could also try custom orientation. Select the face which is planar to the dial, create a custom orientation from face and rotate the dial along that axis. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2g-eG6KkCk&feature=emb_title