# Screw is not rotating, but wobbling

Tags: animation, keyframes

I've got two parts that are supposed to screw into each other, but I am struggling to get Blender to do it correctly. Instead of keeping the axis of rotation constant (like a screw going directly into a wall) it wobbles. I have attached a video of what happens. Sometimes blender does this to me and sometimes it doesn't. I don't know what I'm doing differently.

https://youtu.be/fNW-pUmjK0o

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: because for rotations Blender struggles to find a good interpolation when the local axis are not aligned with the global axis, maybe my answer will help here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: @moonboots It's a quibble, but I wouldn't call this 'Blender struggling'. The wobble is a perfectly valid interpolation of each of the XYZ Euler rotations, in whatever order they are executed.. which is _not the same thing_  as the great-circle route across the sphere from one point to another. All 3D apps do the same. Interpolated Quaternions  _do_  give you the great-circle route.. if Blender was having trouble with those, that would be cause for complaint. Of course, the parenting in your linked answer is absolutely right. :)

Comment: yes "struggling" is not appropriate but I would say "fail" because even quaternion doesn't always give the expected result (plus it's hard to go for more than 180° if I remember correctly), at least in my tests  :((  thus the empty trick which makes it work 100%, am I missing the right way?