# Problem when rotating object in ZZ

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

im having to rotate a 3D wheel in an special perspective which is 3/4, i'm trying to rotate it in Z (pressing twice Z looks great for rotating the object) but when i do this, and save the last keyframe (this doesnt happen when moving it) the object rotates on diffent directions, not the one i did and that i even seen when doing it.

I cannot rotate it from the menu, since i need to move it doing it with auto key and pressing ZZ twice, because thats how its look okay, but the keyframes do something weird.

How can i fix this?

Comment: hello, maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select different rotation order to achieve correct result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!