# how to rotate something about a non perpendicular axis?

Tags: animation, transforms, axis

observe the following airplane model

[image]

how do I rotate this control surface about where it joins the rest of the model? also since the rotation has to be replicated on the other side is there any way to copy the angle both meshes make with each other?

Comment: you could make sure that the origin's orientation is aligned with the topology of your object, then rotate the object on its local axis (R then double X for example), but if you plan to animate, the best is probably to keep it aligned with the global axis and parent to an empty, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill/129836