# Rotate an object on itself

Tags: animation

I need the cylinder to rotate on itself, as in the first image, but as soon as I change its position, the rotation goes strange, see the second picture, so I guess I am doing something wrong. I tried to change the pivot point by adding an empty and so on, but I got the same result.

Thanks in advance for the help, this forum is a blessing!

[image: The rotation I need, the position I don't want]

[image: The position I need and the rotation I don't want]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one but it did work, I don't if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Possibly you’ve rotated it in Edit mode rather than Object mode. In Edit mode you’re affecting the geometry while leaving the objects actual axes of rotation unaffected. If you rotate it in Object mode then then axes will also be rotated and so when you then rotate it around its length then it won’t wobble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your object in **object mode** press **'Ctrl + A'** and apply **rotation and scale**, turn on the **auto keyframing** option(the white dot on the timeline with a grey background), select your object in **object mode**, press **'R'** and left-click without rotating your cylinder so that a keyframe could be set in the timeline, then go to whatever frame you would want your animation to end and then rotate your cylinder on the **'X' axis** by pressing **'S and X' together**.

[image]