# Rotation from center of object

Tags: animation

I'm creating a headphones animation and trying to animate rotate this dial but its not rotating properly. I adjusted the 3d cursor to rotate center of the object but it's not rotating in the angle I need.

[image]

Comment: You might take a look at this part of the Blender manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html?highlight=transformation%20orientation

Comment: Also, this part of the manual about Pivot point, especially the Pivot Types section: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html?highlight=transform%20pivot%20point

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to align the pivot of the dial you need to align the pivot to the face where the dial points. To do this, you must first set the snapping type to "Face Project", set the snap with to "Center" and "Align Rotation to Target"

[image: Snap To panel]

Then in Move tool properties panel activate "Affect Only Origin"

[image: Move tools properties]

Now press G key to move the pivot, and press and hold Ctrl key to snap the pivot on the top of outside face from dial.

[image: Origin to face]

One click to finish the movement and to finish, we have to put the pivot in the center of the object, for that we go to the menu "Object> Set Origin> Origin to Geometry"

[image]

Now you can animate the dial on the z axis rotation.

Here is a [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZhnK.jpg) with the process of this explanation.