# Rotation of an object between 3 axes

Tags: animation, axis

I've been trying to get a propeller on an aircraft to rotate but the problem is that it's angled slightly upwards and is inbetween the x and y-axis. I have tried to use local tranform orientations, use the plane itself as a transform orientation, use different types of pivot points, use quaternion rotations. I've managed to get the propeller to spin a couple of times but it's always one of 2 things: either it spins on multiple axes even if I restrict it to one axis, or it uses only one axis but spins partially.

I feel like I have run out of solutions at this point so I'm hoping someone more experienced can help me out. The red arrow is where the plane is facing, while the blue is the direction I'm trying to make it spin.

[image: here is a picture of what im dealing with;]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129836/35559) help?

Comment: thank you so much, this was exactly what i needed. its wierd how hard it is to get a fix for something this basic