# Rotate Wheel with camber applied

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

[image]Hello everyone, I’m trying to create an animation of an F1 car driving down a road.

I’m using a pre-made 3D model, and the problem I’m having is that the wheel model already has a slight tilt (camber) applied to it.

So when I try to rotate it around the X axis it just wobbles around. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129836/35559) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Change your *Transform Orientation* (Top center - says "Global") to "Local" or "Normal" before rotating your object and/or adding keyframes to the rotation. The object's *rotation axes* will become localized, based on the objects rotation.

[image: NormPP]