# How to rotate an object correct

Tags: axis

I'm trying to rotate this object on the Z axis but the rotation doesn't do what I want it to do. This bar is connected to a steering wheel so the bar should be fixed in this angle and just rotate and not move.

I tried to set the local axis with the help of the face on the top but it didn't work. When I rotate the axis it moves. I want to make an animation using key frames.

How can I fix this rotation problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe check this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: I'm not sure if that's exactly the same thing I want to do. Or I'm not really comfortable with Blender so I understand that case connected to my case.

Comment: what does it gives if you reset the rotation of your object to make it vertical, parent it to an empty, tilt the empty, and keyframe the rotation?

Comment: The orientation of the axis of rotation can be right, while the origin is wrong. You appear to be rotating about Bounding Box center. The Bounding Box is aligned to object axes, (You can see it: 'Bounds' in Viewport display) Its center is not necessarily on the desired axis of rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that you want to set your custom transform orientation that you have created (called *Face.001*) to your object itself. You may do this using this set of actions:

1. Enable **Affect only origins** from **Options** menu

[image]

2. Click **Object** ⇾ **Transform** ⇾ **Align object to transform orientation**. (Because of *Affect only origins* the object will stay in place, only it's orientation will move)
3. Don't forget to disable back **Affect only origins** from **Options** menu

Then it is done, you may use local transforms (that you have pointed on sidebar) to animate your object

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the Transform Pivot point to be the 3D cursor then positioning the 3D Cursor at the bottom face of your object ?

1. **Transform Orientation** to **Local**.
2. **Transform Pivot Point** to **3D Cursor**.
3. Select bottom face of your object.
4. **SHFT S**  > **Cursor to Selected**.
5. **A** to **Salect All**
6. **R Z** to rotate around the local Z axis.

[image]

Comment: This works if I just want to rotate it but it do not work when I am using key frames. Then the problem occurs when it is not rotating only on z-axis.