# Accretion disk can't be rotated

Tags: animation

I just started with blender and after the almighty donut I crossed alaskanFX with his black hole tutorial.

To do that I want to rotate the accretion disk. I got now that it is somehow locked to be able to be rotated in real time. When i apply the rotation it is able to be rotated. Scaling and grabbing works without any issue.

I guess that's my issue to be able to keyframe it?

Thanks in advance!

---

Firstly thanks for all your help ! (I just removed the Rotation constraint which didn't end up in any optical change so I guess that's the easiest solution)

So I am now able to rotate the disc but I still got an issue that when I want to animate it I add a keyframe at frame 0, take the Z axis on the viewport and rotate it. This works as intentended and in the preview while I am rotating the disc it spins without any change of perspective.

When I now add the 2nd keyframe at frame 600 and insert the keyframes and press play it starts spinning arround the world Z axis instead of the local one of the disc. ( I did press R and double Z to rotate the disc so it should be the right one I suppose).

Thanks again for your help and I am sorry for my problems :(

That's the .blend file:
[image]

[image: That's how it looks so it's maybe a bit easier to understand]

Comment: Hello, it's a bit hard to understand, I'm not sure that it's your problem here but if you want the disc to rotate on its own axis, maybe keep it aligned with the global axis, parent to an empty and tilt the empty instead? see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you already have a keyframe somewhere.  Pick a new frame and key it to a different rotation and you'll see that between those frames it will rotate

Comment: I already tried that multiple times but I can't even rotate it without any keyframe :(

Comment: Please share your .blend file with [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to add the provided link.

Comment: I don't know the tutorial and so I don't know how much they epxlain about what they are doing there. But your accretion disk has a _Copy Rotation_ constraint, which makes it copy the rotation (as the name says) of the _Target_ object, the hidden "Circle". This keeps you from creating a different rotation, so you have to remove the constraint.

Comment: Please do not edit your post to add new questions. Create a [new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the constraint as mentioned by @moonboots and @GordonBrinkmann will also remove any rotation obtained from it. If you want to keep that rotation, you can apply the constraint instead (hover it and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

---

But, **if you need to keep the constraint** (which I guess the tutorial expects), either:

1. Rotate the circle instead, since he's the one wearing the rotation.
2. (Better IMHO) Change the constraint's Mix option to "Add":

   [image]

   This way you are able to both copy the circle rotation AND rotate the plane how you want.

Answer (score 1):

*Accretion Disc* has a *Rotation* constraint, that's why it can't rotate:

[image]