# Rotate locally with keyframes

Tags: animation

When rotating the object locally on the Z axis, the rotation is correct if I do it manually, but if I add a keyframe at the beginning and another at the end, the interpolation does not respect the rotation axis. The beginning and the end are correct, but the intermediate frames are not.

[Watch video](https://youtu.be/1gjE0iAeEaU?si=T-SlWNWBHF7nUxMK) (YouTube)

How can I run the animation and have it behave respecting the local Z axis rotation?

[image]

Comment: 3D softwares struggle with this kind of rotation animations, the solution is to parent your object to an empty and tilt the empty, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by axis execution order. By default, it is XYZ:

[image]

This means that rotations applied in local X axis, then local Y, and after that Z, so that than it comes to Z, object is already rotated somehow, and Z axis is not local anymore.

To fix that, Z axis should go first:

[image]

If you want to keep rotation then changing execution order, do if thought quaternions (keyframes should be removed):

[image]