How do I rotate a cap off?
I'm animating an object and want to rotate the cap off, moving it from its original position (Point A) to a diagonal one on the right (Point B).
If the bottle weren't tilted, I could simply adjust the Z-axis rotation value from 0 to 360. However, since it is tilted, how can I achieve a realistic rotation effect?
As you can tell, I'm new to Blender and animations.



hello, maybe read this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

Thank you! This was helpful. I had to watch a tutorial on how empties work, but I think I've figured it out:

Create an empty and parent it to the cap
Select both the empty and the cap, and rotate them to the desired angle
Adjust the Z-axis value of the empty


no, make sure that the cap is aligned with the global axis (and that its local axis is aligned with the object), parent it to an empty, tilt the empty, keyframe the rotation of the cap on its Z axis

Reset the rotation of your cap, make sure that its local axis is aligned with its top face (if it's not the case you'll need to correct that):

Parent the cap to an empty:

Move and rotate the empty the way you want:

Rotate the cap on its own axis and keyframe this rotation, as it is now parented to the empty, its new world reference is the empty and the rotation calculation will be easy and correct:


Thank you! I was able to solve this problem by following your comment above but I really appreciate the step by step process and will probably refer to it again!
