How to Animate object along its Local axis?
I want cut these wooden sticks with wood cutter saw but I don't know how to animate saw along its local rotation.
I mean , I want saw remain tilt and spin tilt. please guide me how to do so.

Hello, this looks as if it has been effectively answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129836/35559 . Please let us know if this is a fix for you, and if not, why not, linking back to that post.
