Animate rotation
I've keyframed a cylindrical object to rotate, but, on playback, the rotation is different than desired.  The first keyframe shows the object at 0 degrees X and Z, 90 degrees at Y axis.  The desired, open ended rotation, which is reached by rotating on the red rotation axis (the same result as shown here being rotated on the white outside circle), then keyframed, is shown here:
However, after keyframing, the playback is showing something similar to this, which is not desired.     
Have tried several transformation orientation settings, but can't figure it out.  Sure will appreciate the advise!

Actually I'm not sure what is going on with your model because it seems to be distorted by rotation. This could only mean you have some modifiers or other things which are varying dependent on the rotation - however you do not give any information on this in your question, so we cannot help you with the appearance without more details. You say the first keyframe shows the object at (0°, 90°, 0°), but the screenshot clearly shows the values (89.801°, 126.5°, 88.635°). And although the keyframe is not set to these values (see below), these are the ones currently used to show the object in the viewport.
But unless you did not change anything on your animation and the keyframes, what you show there is not what you will get if you playback the animation or render it:
You can see it in the colors of the keyframed values. The lower screenshot shows the rotation values in green, this means there are keyframes on those channels, but not on the frame you are currently on and the values are just interpolated inbetween. In your example, keyframes are on frame 1 and 40, but the current frame in the lower screenshot is 14, so the values are interpolated between the keyframes.

The orange color in the upper screenshot shows, these channels have animation keyframes, but the values which are shown have been changed and not yet been set as a keyframe - which means, moving the timeline or rendering etc. will reset them to the keyframed (or interpolated) values. The yellow color of the text in the top left where the frame number, collection and object name are shown also indicates that it has keyframes on the current frame.

When you are on a frame where you have keyframes and the values are the unaltered ones set in the keyframe, the color will be yellow.


Thanks, Gordon.  All of your points are correct.  I had initially made an mp4 showing each step along the way, but, as a newbie here, didn't know that mp4's weren't accepted format.  So I did struggle trying to pick frames which I hoped would make my point...but I now see that I picked a bunch of incorrect points.  Will do better on my next post.  Nevertheless, you've made several points that I'll explore in more depth.  Thanks!

@user187768 Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, if some post helped you upvote it. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos You have closed the question. Can answers be accepted when the question is closed? I have no idea because I have no closed questions with answers to try. I only know that you cannot write answers for closed questions.

@GordonBrinkmann That is a good question, I don't have one I can test with either, but I have no reason to believe they can't. According to this post yes, owners of closed questions can still mark an answer as accepted https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91827/can-an-answer-of-a-closed-question-be-accepted

I agree that this question should be deleted.  The link to the post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill provided the answer to the question.  Thanks!

@user187768 And that's why we usually just close but do not delete duplicate questions here... someone with a similar problem might not use matching search words to find the other question, but maybe finds yours and then the link to the other answer.
