How can I animate this simple fan spinning?
I am trying to make a simple fan spinning animation for a video game but I am not exactly sure how it's supposed to spin on its own axis/pivot. As you can see the fan is looking a bit downwards. Here is what I would like to make with keyframes:

But when I rotate it from the same view, it rotates on a horizontal axis instead of keeping its angle.
Do you know how to get this fan to spin on its own angle/axis? Thanks for your help in advance!

an object will struggle to rotate on an axis if it is already rotated on another one, maybe this is your problem? See my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill If it doesn't answer, please share your file

I have tried based on that tutorials but I must have missed something or Blender changed quite a bit since, but it's still not spinning on its own angle/axis unfortunately :/
I will include the fan here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5-lEKFULFkif1IUrY_zr8bcT8jJriCf/view?usp=sharing

Looks like I figured it out, luckily it also works in the game so everything works now!
Thank you regardless!

@moonboots you can rotate objects around their local axis if you press the button of the axis twice after pressing R. Or you can change the Transform Orientations available to you at the top of the viewport.

OK but it doesn't work once you animate it if the object is always rotated on one of its axis

If it's for a video game, it would be better to use an armature object with bones to animate, rather than animating different objects. Otherwise in the game engine you would have to deal with one different animation asset per object.
Plus it would make this animation simpler to make using bones. With one root bone, parent of a body bone, parent of the fan blades bone, you can have the fan blade mode freely rotate on its local axis while its body bone orient the whole thing in any way you want without interfering with the fan blades animation.


